# One Application Fill All

Tags: jquery, windows, html, web, hybrid-mobile-app

I want to develop an application which can run on windows and web both the version.
Later i also want same code to run on android(hybrid) version.
I have an application which has 3 development environment like asp.net web, vb.net windows application and one hybrid android app.
But the problem is every time when new functionality is introduced, I have to apply the same change in 3 different codes and its very tedious process.

Can anyone please suggest me for which framework or technology i have to go with???
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could substitute the ff:

- ASP.NET with [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/)
- VB.NET with [Electron by Github](http://electron.atom.io/)
- Android App with [Ionic Framework](https://ionicframework.com/)

All of this technologies can be made with web technologies and are mostly javascript.

**NodeJS** - 
  is a JavaScript runtime built on Chrome's V8 JavaScript engine. Node.js uses an event-driven, non-blocking I/O model that makes it lightweight and efficient.

**Common description of NodeJS is, javascript on the server side.**

**Electron** (formerly Atom Shell) is one of GitHub developed, open source framework . It enables the development of graphical desktop applications using the Node.js frameworks, originally for the development of Web applications was used. Electron is the basis of two known free source code editors: Atom (developed by Github) and Visual Studio Code (developed by Microsoft ).

Source https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_(Framework)

**Ionic Framework**
 - is a complete open-source SDK for hybrid mobile app development.[4] Built on top of AngularJS and Apache Cordova, Ionic provides tools and services for developing hybrid mobile apps using Web technologies like CSS, HTML5, and Sass.

Source https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionic_(mobile_app_framework)